# Fallout New Vegas Freeze on Bethesda Loading Screen (before main menu)

Tags: technical-issues, fallout-new-vegas

Up until recently, Fallout New Vegas played just fine on my PC, However, I went to play it yesterday and the game loads as far as the Bethesda splash screen (before the main menu) and then freezes. The only way I can get out of this is to restart the PC.

I have tried validating my Steam cache and I've also tried re-installing the game, to no avail.

I do not have any mods installed. My DxDiag can be found here - http://pastebin.com/gLvyewRw

Comment: problems aside, you should install a 64bit OS if you have more than 4gb of RAM...

Comment: Did your copy of Fallout NV use Games for Windows Live, or is it the Steam version? GFWL shutting down is killing a lot of games.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie It's the Steam version. Otherwise, *I have tried validating my Steam cache* would be fairly fruitless.

Comment: @kalina can't really afford it right now. Maybe in the new year.

Comment: Then I am out of ideas. D:

Comment: @SevenSidedDie GFWL hasn't shut down yet, though. Still works fine for games that use it. In fact, it's "shutdown" is just a rumor that puts it at July of next year.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Isn't Fallout New Vegas Steam only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found someone else who had been having the same issue, and they reported that exiting Raptr before playing solved the issue. I just tested this and the game loaded fine.

**To resolve this problem, exit Raptr** (assuming you're using it - if not, I'm afraid I don't know)